# How can I get a postgres query with an ORDER BY to do an index only scan?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a fairly large table in which the most common API request is something like:

`/api/orders?status=confirmed`

The actual SQL generated to serve this request is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE account_id = 'X' AND status = 'confirmed' AND versionID IS NULL 
ORDER BY int_id;
```

For the life of me I can't figure out what index will make this perform really well, running on postgres 9.5.4.

I created an index on `(account_id, status, versionID)` which makes things blazing fast on the same query minus the `ORDER BY` (it uses an "index only scan"), but as soon as that `ORDER BY` is on there, it reverts back to a combination of "bitmap heap scan" and "bitmap index scan" which is 50-100x slower.

I also tried creating an index on `(int_id ASC, account_id, status, versionID)` and the query planner seemed to ignore it completely.

Any ideas as to how to construct an index that will serve the full query using an "index only scan" or something equivalently fast?

Comment: Are you sure this is the full story? Could you post some schema? I can't seem to replicate your problem:

`create table orders (orders_id serial primary key, account_id text not null, status text not null, version_id int null);
insert into orders (account_id, status, version_id) select generate_series(1, 100000), 'confirmed', null;
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE account_id = '1' AND status = 'confirmed' AND version_id IS NULL 
ORDER BY orders_id;
`

gives me an index-only scan.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the where clause filters are consistent, you can make the index smaller if you include the static filters:

`CREATE INDEX test_idx1 ON orders (account_id, int_id ASC NULLS LAST)
WHERE status = 'confirmed' AND versionID IS NULL`

That index would have each account, ordered by int_id. I find it's helpful to explicitly set the ORDER BY the same as the index, so you can prove it's working:

`SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE account_id = 'X' AND status = 'confirmed' AND versionID IS NULL 
ORDER BY int_id ASC NULLS LAST;`

If you can change from SELECT * to a list of columns, you can also make it better:

`SELECT address, name
FROM orders
WHERE account_id = 'X' AND status = 'confirmed' AND versionID IS NULL 
ORDER BY int_id;`

Then this should do an index-only scan:

`CREATE INDEX test_idx2 ON orders (account_id, int_id, address, name)
WHERE AND status = 'confirmed' AND versionID IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM orders o
WHERE account_id = 'X' AND status = 'confirmed' AND versionID IS NULL 
ORDER BY int_id;
```

The optimal index is a composite index on `(account_id, status, versionID, int_id)`.  `int_id` should be the last key in the index, because the `order by` should take place after the filtering in the `where` clause.